# 32 x 8 Register file using generate statement for D-flip flops

Tags: vhdl

My circuit has a grid of 32 x 8 D flip flops. each row should be producing a 32 bit vectors that contain the Q values from the D-ff's - which are then sent to a 8x1 MUX. The following code is me trying to properly generate the 32 x 8 D flip flops and test if I can get a vector out of them (the 32 bit I0 vector).

the circuit I'm trying to write the implementation for can be seen in the figure posted in this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418555/test-bench-of-a-32x8-register-file-vhdl?rq=1

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity REG is
port (
    CLK         : in std_logic;
    WRT_REG_NUM : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    WRT_DATA    : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    READ_REG_A  : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    READ_REG_B  : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    PORT_A      : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    PORT_B      : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
);
end REG;

architecture BEHV_32x8_REG of REG is
-- decoder component
component DCDR
    port (
        I_in    : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        O_out   : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end component;
-- D flip flop component
component D_FF
    port (
        D_in    : in    std_logic;
        CLK     : in    std_logic;
        Q_out   : out   std_logic;
        QN_out  : out   std_logic   -- Q not
    );
end component;
-- MUX copmonent
component MUX
    port (
        S_in                            : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        I7, I6, I5, I4, I3, I2, I1, I0  : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        O_out                           : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
    );
end component;

-- internal signals used
signal I_in     : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
signal O_out    : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal CLK_vals : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal I0       : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal QN_out   : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);


begin

-- decoder instance
DCDR1 : DCDR port map(I_in, O_out);

GEN_D_FF1:
for ROW in 0 to 7 generate
    GEN_D_FF2:
    for COL in 0 to 31 generate
        DFF_X : D_FF port map(WRT_DATA(COL), CLK_vals(ROW), I0(COL), QN_out(COL));
    end generate GEN_D_FF2;
end generate GEN_D_FF1; 

DCDR_AND : process
begin
    I_in <= WRT_REG_NUM;

    for I in 0 to 7 loop
        CLK_vals(I) <= O_out(I) and CLK;
    end loop;
    wait for 10 ns;
end process DCDR_AND;

end BEHV_32x8_REG;
```

EDIT: adding a screen shot of a simulation run
[image: Simulation]

When I simulate the above code in ModelSim, I don't get any output for I0. Where is my design flawed? Am I violating any VHDL best practices? Assuming I can get this to function properly, how could I get 8 different 32-bit vectors (from each row of flip flops) to send to the MUX(s)?

I appreciate any advice I receive!

Comment: Your IO signal bits seem to be hooked to the Q_out of each flip flop.  So where is the code for your flip-flop's behavior? Have you actually tested a single one to make sure your flip-flop code is correct? Also, a timing diagram from ISim would be extremely useful in troubleshooting this, to be able to see the values of signals and inputs

Comment: Yes I've written a test bench for the D_FF and have made sure it behaves correctly. I'll edit in a picture of a simulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flip-flops trigger when the CLK value changes (assuming your flip-flop code is correct here). Your flip-flop component,

```
component D_FF
    port (
        D_in    : in    std_logic;
        CLK     : in    std_logic;
        Q_out   : out   std_logic;
        QN_out  : out   std_logic   -- Q not
    );
end component;
```

has the CLK input tied to `CLK_vals(ROW)`, from this line:

```
DFF_X : D_FF port map(WRT_DATA(COL), CLK_vals(ROW), I0(COL), QN_out(COL));
```

Yet the `CLK_vals` never change, as evident by your timing diagram, after the initial 10ns wait when it is uninitialized.

Your `CLK_vals` is setup here:

```
CLK_vals(I) <= O_out(I) and CLK;
```

Yet neither `O_out` nor `CLK` change.

O_out stays '00100000', and CLK stays '1'

You need to have an alternating clock.  Something simple, like

```
signal CLK : std_logic := '0';
CLK <= not CLK after 5ns;
```

I have read both sides of the fence as far as needing to initialize values, you can read a little bit about that here. But it would get rid of those ugly red Us

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363130/is-there-a-reason-to-initialize-not-reset-signals-in-vhdl-and-verilog

Comment: Ahh this is helpful - and I've accepted it as the answer. However, I was also hoping for some advice as far as correct design for generating the D_FFs as well as sending their Q values to the MUX. Write now I just have the I0 vector being populated, and I'll be able to send that, but I have no hard variable names for the other 7 vectors that I need - do I send each vector from within the generate statements?

Comment: As far as generating the flip-flops, it looks like you have that down.  Your generate statement looks fine. My professors personally tell us to always use the more verbose version though, with the '=>' and then the name of the signal so it's less easy to get confused.

It looks like right now you have all of your flip-flops connecting to the same signals.  The only differentiating element between the 8 groups of 32 is the CLK_vals

Comment: @TylerPlude - See the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22738142/nested-generate-statements-for-32-x-8-register-vhdl/22739737#22739737) to mostly the same question on stackoverflow

Comment: It would definitely help to use arrays for this.  You are going to need to create 8 separate 32-bit vectors to tie in to your muxes.  Currently you only have one. EDIT: Ah, apparently David's answer says the same thing!

Comment: Yes haha - I kept watching the '# views' go up but no responses so I posted it in both locations. Thank you both!